# Upper bound for the $\sup$ of a martingale defined as a stochastic integral of a general continuous martingale

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Consider a probability filtred space  $ (\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathcal F_ t, \mathbb P)$ and a continuous $\mathcal F _t$-martingal starting from $0$, $ M = (M_t)_{t \geq 0}$, such that $\left \langle M \right \rangle_\infty \leq 1$ $\mathbb P$-ps.
Now, we define by recurence $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$  I^{(o)}_t \equiv  1, \ I^{(n+1)}_t  \int _0 ^t I^{(n)}_s d M_s \ , \ t \geq 0 $$

**The question:** How to show that  $I^{(n)}$ is a $\mathcal F _t $-martingal with $I^{(n)}_t$ in $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ and  that we have

$$ \mathbb{E} \left \{  \sup_ {t \geq 0} \left | I^{(n)}_t \right | ^2   \right \} \leq 4^n $$

**Element of answer:** for the last inequality we can maybe start using Burkholder-Davis-Gundy inequality, then we'll have :

\begin{align} \mathbb{E} \left \{  \sup_ {0 \leq t \leq T} \left | I^{(n)}_t \right | ^2   \right \} & \overset{BDG}{\leq} C\mathbb{E} \left \{   \left \langle I^{(n)} \right \rangle_T  \right \}  \\&= C\mathbb{E} \left \{  \int_0 ^T \left |I^{(n-1)}_s\right | ^2 d\left \langle M\right \rangle _s  \right \} \\ & \overset{Fubini}{=} C  \int_0 ^T \mathbb{E} \left \{\left |I^{(n-1)}_s\right | ^2 \right \}d\left \langle M\right \rangle _s \\ & \overset{Ito's isometry}{=}  C  \int_0 ^T \mathbb{E} \left \{\int _0 ^s\left |I^{(n-2)}_s\right | ^2 d\left \langle M\right \rangle _{s_1}\right \}d\left \langle M\right \rangle _s \\ &=(...) \\& = C  \int_0 ^T \int_0 ^s \int_0 ^{s_1} ... \int_0 ^{s_n-2} 1 \  d\left \langle M\right \rangle _{s_{n-2}} ... d\left \langle M\right \rangle _{s_2} d\left \langle M\right \rangle _{s_1}  d\left \langle M\right \rangle _{s}\end{align}

**EDIT**

**Did sugestion:** Could you please, check if I understood ?

You should notice that all the steps where the Fubini's theorem was applied are wrong!

\begin{align} \mathbb{E} \left \{  \sup_ {0 \leq t \leq T} \left | I^{(n)}_t \right | ^2   \right \} & \overset{BDG}{\leq} 4\mathbb{E} \left \{   \left \langle I^{(n)} \right \rangle_T  \right \}  \\&=4\mathbb{E} \left \{  \int_0 ^T \left |I^{(n-1)}_s\right | ^2 d\left \langle M\right \rangle _s  \right \} 
\\ & \overset{Fubini}{=} 4  \int_0 ^T \mathbb{E} \left \{\left |I^{(n-1)}_s\right | ^2 \right \}d\left \langle M\right \rangle _s 
\\ & \overset{}{\leq} 4  \int_0 ^T \mathbb{E} \left \{\sup_{0\leq u \leq s}\left |I^{(n-1)}_u\right | ^2 \right \}d\left \langle M\right \rangle _s 
\\ & \overset{BDG}{=}  4 ^2 \int_0 ^T \mathbb{E} \left \{\int _0 ^s\left |I^{(n-2)}_s\right | ^2 d\left \langle M\right \rangle _{s_1}\right \}d\left \langle M\right \rangle _s \\ &=(...) 
\\& \leq 4^n  \int_0 ^T \int_0 ^s \int_0 ^{s_1} ... \int_0 ^{s_n-2} 1 \  d\left \langle M\right \rangle _{s_{n-2}} ... d\left \langle M\right \rangle _{s_2} d\left \langle M\right \rangle _{s_1}  d\left \langle M\right \rangle _{s}\\ &\leq 4^n\end{align}
because $\left \langle M \right \rangle = (\left \langle M \right \rangle_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is an increasing process with $\left \langle M \right \rangle_\infty \leq 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is direct if [one recalls that $C=4$](http://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/03/29/quadratic-variations-and-the-ito-isometry/#scn_itoisom_lem2) and if one replaces $\left |I^{(n-1)}_s\right | ^2$ by $\sup\limits_{s\geqslant 0}\left |I^{(n-1)}_s\right | ^2$ as soon as possible (and note that the localization by $t\leqslant T$ is not needed).

Comment: Can you detail the calculation please?

Comment: It IS detailed (just read).

Comment: Could you please, check at the end of the question if I understood ? I still do not understand how to complete the proof neither why it is not necessary to localizate by $t\leq T$.

Comment: Edit part, second line of displayed equations: $C=4$. Third line and every subsequent line: this is not Fubini, watch out for random variables vs constants. Everywhere: please follow *closely* my hint.

Comment: OP: Why not trying to follow my suggestions? One of the first things to do is to correct the identity in the third line (the one topped by the mention *Fubini*), which is invalid because $d\langle M\rangle_s$ is random, hence it must stay **inside** the integral.